# How can I sort GitHub pull requests by the time they were merged?

Tags: sorting, github, pull-request

I would like to look at all merged pull requests in the order in which they were merged. So far GitHub only provides sorting for most recently updated which would work if I didn't have other updates being done to the branches after they were merged (deleting of old branches etc).